# Mysql Count Several fields

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a table

```
id|user_id|start|stop
 1|      1|    1|   1
 2|      2|    1|   1
 3|      2|    1|   0
 4|      3|    0|   0
```

I want to get next result

```
user_id|total|start|stop
      1|    1|    1|   1
      2|    2|    2|   1
      3|    1|    0|   0
```

So i want to make 3 count and group it by user_id ang get. Is it possible to prepare query with Joins and without derived tables?

Comment: How are `start` and `stop` calculated for `user_id=2`?

Comment: how did you get next result based on the table you have??

Comment: It seems like the row for user_id = 2 should be `2|    *3*|    2|   1`

Comment: @Kevin: No, there are 2 rows with `user_id=2`. Why should it be `3`?

Comment: I see - I thought that total would be the sum of all starts and all stops. (i.e. start + stop)

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah, that might be wanted. But probably it isn't, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total row as to count rows with 1 in `start` and 1 in `stop` *twice*.

```
SELECT user_id, 
   count(case start WHEN 1 then 1 else null end) AS start, 
   count(case stop WHEN 1 then 1 else null end)  AS stop, 
   count (*) AS total 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY user_id
```

Comment: Count function will count for both value 0 or 1 in the column. So result will be wrong. Op want to know how many times a user start and stop and total number of records for that user_id.

Comment: I misunderstood the question and have corrected my answer. Would you mind removing the down vote?

Comment: @Kevin, I want to know whether SUM will be fast than Case in the current scenario.

Comment: Unless the table is very, very large the differences should be very minimal. Also, it depends on your indexing strategy. But it should be very similar.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user_id, 
       Sum (start) AS start, 
       Sum (stop)  AS stop, 
       Count(*)    AS total 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY user_id
```

Comment: Even though in this case `count` gives the same answer as `sum`, I'd recommend using `count` anyway - if the data in the table changes and values other than 0 or 1 are allowed, it will still work.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   user_id, COUNT(*) total, SUM(start=1) start, SUM(stop=1) stop
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY user_id
```